# Why are the properties 'height' and 'width' not adjusting the picture size in Excel through xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, image, xlwings

I'm trying to copy an image of a matplotlib graph from python into Excel using xlwings. I am able to successfully do this but the image is too large once copied over to Excel. I've tried to change the size of the image using the 'height' and 'width' properties of the pictures() function in xlwings but this doesn't adjust the image. Below is my code for the graph in python and the code to paste it in Excel.

```
import xlwings as xw
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

graphsht = xw.books.active.sheets('Graphs')

#Import data
data = pd.read_excel(open('Test_Data.xlsx', 'rb'), index_col=0)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,7))
x = pdf.plot(lw=2, label='PDF', legend=True)
data.plot(kind='hist', bins=50, density=True, alpha=0.5, label='Data', legend=True, ax=ax)
plt.title('Distribution')
        
#Output histogram to workbook
graphsht.pictures.add(fig, name='Distribution',left=graphsht.range('B2').left, top=graphsht.range('B2').top, height=250, width=300)
```

If I adjust the figsize, this does change the size of the image outputted to Excel, but the font size of the title and axes title stays exactly the same and again looks too large.

Comment: You realize that width and height are given in points, right?  That 250x300 equates to 3.5x4.2 inches.

Comment: I do. I can change that to 50x100 or 500x600 and the picture size stays exactly the same.

Comment: might be a bug. I ran a script today that worked previously and the images are not resizing... I did update xlwings today to find broken image resizing, I reverted to 0.19.1 and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your update is TRUE and whenever you run your code, the picture overwrites with the existing attribute. it is better to change your name in graphsht.pictures.add() in each running